# MSSQL Where username's authority is one of the required

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I've created a function that will check the authority of the user on specific pages. It's supposed to return either 0 or 1. This is the function I use on pages.
This part is not the issue though, as this works as intended.

```
$admin_model = $this->loadModel('AdminModel');
if($admin_model->checkAdmin($_SESSION['username']) == 0) {
    header('Location: ' . URL);
    exit();
}
```

Here is where the issue lies. My account has the authority of M and therefore this should return the value 1, but it returns 0 instead.

```
public function checkAdmin($account) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE
            account = :account AND authority = 'L' OR
            account = :account AND authority = 'M' OR
            account = :account AND authority = 'N' OR
            account = :account AND authority = 'O' OR
            account = :account AND authority = 'P'";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':account' => $account));

    return $query->rowCount();
}
```

I also tried using this query in SQL Management Studio, and it works. Why doesn't the query work in PHP, though?

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE
account = 'ibab' AND authority = 'L' OR
account = 'ibab' AND authority = 'M' OR
account = 'ibab' AND authority = 'N' OR
account = 'ibab' AND authority = 'O' OR
account = 'ibab' AND authority = 'P';
```

Comment: "_You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on._" http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Turn on PDO's exceptions, and it should be complaining about an incorrect number of parameters:  `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` due tot he reuse of `:account` several times.

Comment: You can also rewrite your query so that you pass an account value only once `SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account = :account AND authority IN('L','M','N','O','P')`. And in your original query you should've used parentheses to separate AND groups with OR.

Comment: ^^ Yep, @peterm 's suggestion is probably the best solution, rather than switching to `?` positional params.

Comment: @Michael Berowski I see. I actually thought about this, but the way I tried to work with it was to just add the :account => $account several times to the execute. Thank you.

Comment: @peterm that's worthy of an answer I think

Comment: @peterm Thank you. This is a lot better than how I had thought of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MichaelBerkowski in comments perfectly showed the immediate problem with your code which is using the same named parameter in a prepared statement more than once, which is not allowed.

One of the ways to solve it is to rewrite your query in a more concise way so that you pass an account value only once

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM accounts 
 WHERE account = :account 
   AND authority IN('L','M','N','O','P')
```

*BTW in your original query you should've used parentheses to separate AND groups with OR.*

---

**UPDATE:** As @ÁlvaroG.Vicario mentioned in comments there is no need to return the whole resultset if the end goal is just to figure out whether you have any records or not. You can make use of `COUNT()` for that. You can even add `TOP 1` (assuming you're on SQL Server) if you ever plan to have multiple auth records.

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) flag 
  FROM accounts 
 WHERE account = :account 
   AND authority IN('L','M','N','O','P')
```

It will always give you either 1 or 0 in the `flag` column.

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92972/1)** demo

Comment: Since the result object is actually discarded, I'd also suggest to simply run a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query that returns a single row. It probably won't make a lot of a difference in performance terms but it'll be more readable.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Fair enough. Thanks for your input.